# Gcloud with cloudbuild and Django Postgres cause psycopg2 ImportError

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

I am building a Django based application on App Engine. I have created a Postres CloudSql instance. I created a cloudbuild.yaml file with a Cloud Build Trigger.

django = v2.2

psycopg2 = v2.8.4

GAE runtime: python37

The cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
- name: 'python:3.7'
  entrypoint: python3
  args: ['-m', 'pip', 'install', '-t', '.', '-r', 'requirements.txt']
- name: 'python:3.7'
  entrypoint: python3
  args: ['./manage.py', 'migrate', '--noinput']
- name: 'python:3.7'
  entrypoint: python3
  args: ['./manage.py', 'collectstatic', '--noinput']
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout:   "3000s"
```

The deploymnet is going alright, the app can connect to the database. But when I try load a page I get the next error:
"**...import psycopg2 as Database File "/srv/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in  from psycopg2._psycopg import ( # noqa ImportError: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**"

Another interesting thing is if I deploy my app with 'gcloud app deploy' (not through Cloud Build), everything is alright I am not getting the error above, my app can communicate with the database.

I am pretty new with gcloud, so maybe I missed some basic here. 
But my questions are:

-What is missing from my cloudbuild.yaml to make it work?

-Do I pip install my dependencies to the correct place?

-The prospective of this error what is the difference with the Cloud Build based deployment and the manual one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see you're using Cloud Build to run `gcloud app deploy`.

This command commits your code and configuration files to App Engine. As explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime) App engine runs in a Google managed environment that automatically handles the installation of the dependencies specified in the `requirements.txt` file and executes the entrypoint you defined in your `app.yaml`. This has the benefit of not having to manually trigger the instalation of dependencies. The first two steps of your cloudbuild are not affecting the App Engine's runtime, since the configuration of it is managed by the aforementioned files once they're deployed.

The purpose of [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/overview) is to import source code from a variety of repositories and build binaries or images according to your specifications. It could be used to [build Docker images and push them to a repository](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/create-basic-configuration#creating_a_build_config), [download a file to be included in Docker build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps#creating_a_custom_build_step) or [package a Go binary an upload it to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-go). Furthermore the [gcloud builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gcloud) is aimed to run gcloud commands through a build pipeline for example to create account permissions or configure firewall rules when these are required steps for another operation to succeed.

Since you're not automatizing a build pipeline but trying to deploy an App Engine application Cloud build is not the product you should be using. The way to go when deploying to App Engine is to simply run `gcloud app deploy` command and let Google's environment take care of the rest for you.

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification, I see the limitations now. But, Django has these migration files which update the database scheme. If I make db update in local, is there any way to update the production db scheme based on these migration files as part of some kind of automated deployment process?

Comment: App Engine standard doesn't allow the execution of arbitrary scripts. You should migrate your schema from the local environment pointing to your Cloud SQL instance. Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825154/how-to-make-django-migrations-on-google-cloud-platform)

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this Quickstart describing exactly what the OP was trying to do?
https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories

I myself was hoping to automate deployment of a Django webapp to an AppEngine "standard" instance.

Comment: Please avoid answers like +1. This does not answer the question. Please check it out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer